# Passing parameter with javascript through Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, parameter-passing, url-parameters

So I've been working a widget based off the one listed here: http://php-drops.blogspot.com/2011/04/creating-widget-with-javascript-and-php.html

Users I am trying to create a preview function of the widget so that users can check how it looks like.  The way I'm doing it is passing the the "copy and paste" code portion into a parameter that the "preview" page can grab and echo.  This is working perfectly in firefox and ie, but displays a blank page in Chrome.

When I do a view source on the blank page in Chrome, the source code is the same as in firefox and ie.  When I copy and paste the code from the "view page source" onto a new page, it displays perfectly in Chrome.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I should be looking for?  And was I breaking some sort of rule by passing javascript in a parameter- a rule that firefox and ie didn't care about but Chrome did?

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

http://imaginarydomain.com/widget/example.php?widget_script=%3Cscript+type%3D%22text%2Fjavascript%22%3Edocument.write('hello%20world')%3C%2Fscript%3E

View page source on chrome would show:

```
         <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
         <html><head></head><body><script type="text/javascript">document.write('hello world')</script>
        </body></html>
```

But the page would be blank.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You probably need to escape your single quotes by changing `'` to `\'` before encoding.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to Chrome's XSS attack filter, which prevents javascript from being passed.

When I had checked the javascript console on chrome, I got

"Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request."

After a quick scan of what to do about this, I've found none of the options very attractive.